# Concept of a static variable inside a function when called by string.replace

Tags: javascript

I have the following code to do a basic IP validation. Actually, it's just academic and I'm using this code to practice using [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) (intentionally using a poor/loose regex):

```js
let potential_ips = [
    '1.2.3.4.5',
    '12.34.45.56',
    '123.456.789.0',
    '1.2.3.4.5.6'
] 
var group_num = 0;
function rePlace(m, g1) {
    group_num ++;
    if (parseInt(g1) > 255) {
        return '<invalid>'
    } else  if (group_num > 4) {
        return '<invalid>'
    } else {
        return m;
    }
}
const regex = /(\d{1,3})\.?/g;
for (ip of potential_ips) {
    group_num = 0;
    ip = ip.replace(regex, rePlace);
    console.log('222', ip);
}
```

What I'm trying to do is when the `.replace` function is called to keep a running total of the number of times it's been called for that particular string. Currently I'm using a `var` at the top-level scope, but I'm wondering if there is a sort of cleaner way to do this within the function itself? What would be a better approach to doing this?

Comment: Just for interest sake, the .replaceAll function can accept a callback / replacer function. Perhaps that could be used to accomplish a count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a closure over the count and initialize with zero.

```js
const
    rePlace = count => m => {
        count++;
        if (parseInt(m) > 255 || count > 4) return '<invalid>';
        return m;
    },
    regex = /\d+(?=(\.|$))/g,
    potential_ips = ['1.2.3.4.5', '12.34.45.56', '123.456.789.0', '1.2.3.4.5.6'];

for (let ip of potential_ips) {
    ip = ip.replace(regex, rePlace(0));
    console.log('222', ip);
}
```

Comment: that's a bit hard for me to read, as I'm pretty new to js. Is that the same as doing the following? (Also, should the `regex` / `potential_ips` be dedented once?) https://jsfiddle.net/69a4x8b5/

Comment: you should declare all variabes. always.

Comment: oh, I see now -- those are three different variables that are all `const`s -- `rePlace`, `regex` and `potential_ips`.

Answer (score 0):

The concept here is copied from Nina's answer, but here is one approach where the `rePlace` function now returns a bound function with an initialized variable to zero (perhaps a bit like Church numerals?)

```js
function rePlace(count) {
    return function(m) {
        count ++;
        return (parseInt(m) > 255 || count > 4) ? '<invalid>' : m;
    }
}

const regex = /\d+(?=(\.|$))/g
const potential_ips = ['1.2.3.4.5', '12.34.45.56', '123.456.789.0', '1.2.3.4.5.6'] ;
for (let ip of potential_ips) {
    ip = ip.replace(regex, rePlace(0));
    console.log('222', ip);
}
```